# Is it possible to sync two tar files

Tags: linux, synchronization, rsync

We need to sync  two **tar / zip files** between two different servers.

Is it is possible to do that sync process Between tar files.

Can you please help us!!!!!

Comment: You mean combining the two archives into one?

Comment: no, we need to sync two tar files ,